# how to get time difference from a specific label

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck in a problem that is hard to explain, take first a dateframe like that:

```
data = [['2022-05-11 12:55:51.177', 4,'D'], ['2022-05-11 13:01:39.773', 4, 'A'],
    ['2022-05-11 15:19:48.060', 4 ,'D'], ['2022-05-09 15:21:04.520', 6,'A'],
    ['2022-05-24 18:05:41.453', 8, 'D'], ['2022-05-24 18:07:02.577', 8, 'D'],
    ['2022-05-24 18:05:42.710', 8, 'A'], ['2022-05-26 18:07:26.153', 8, 'D'],
    ['2022-05-26 18:07:27.153', 8, 'D'], ['2022-05-26 18:07:32.143', 8, 'D']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date_in', 'Number', 'Label'])
```

So I need to find rows with 'A' that was not followed with 'D' for 24 hours (if A is in 05-24 18:00, is not valid if a D is before 05-25 18:00) in the same group (4,6,8), so the solution of this dataframe is:

```
Date_in                  Number     Label
2022-05-24 18:05:42.710    8          A
```

And if the time difference is added it will be a better solution, but with that solution is enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try

```py
out = (df.groupby('Number')
       .apply(lambda g: g[g['Label'].eq('A')    # Select A rows
                          & g['Label'].eq('D').shift(-1)  # Make sure A is followed by D
                          & g['Date_in'].diff().shift(-1).gt(pd.Timedelta(days=1))])
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
print(out)

                  Date_in  Number Label
0 2022-05-24 18:05:42.710       8     A
```

Comment: I think I suits perfectly with this problem, I need a few hours to check it, but I thank you for help me!